# "Gesichtszüge entgleisen", wie nennt man das Konstrukt?

Tags: etymology, terminology, metaphor

Mir fiel jetzt kein weiteres Beispiel außer diesem ein.

Es leuchtet vermutlich allen ein, dass (Eisenbahn-)Züge und entgleisen zusammenpassen. Hingegen passen Gesichtszüge und Eisenbahnen nur bedingt zueinander, und zwar eigentlich *ausschließlich* aufgrund des Wortstamms **Zug**. Entgleisen bezieht sich ja aber ausdrücklich auf die Gleise im Zusammenhang mit (Eisenbahn-)Zügen.

Wie nennt man nun aber so ein Konstrukt, welches, die Wortähnlichkeit ausnutzend, so eine belustigende Parallele zieht?

Comment: Ich würde sagen, das ist ein _Wortspiel_, das mit der rhetorischen Figur der [Paronomasie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paronomasie) eng verwandt ist. Vielleicht könnte man es als einen Spezialfall davon bezeichnen.

Comment: Das Beispiel in der Wikipediaseite der Paronomasie, das am ähnlichsten ist, ist "Lieber arm dran als Arm ab".

Comment: Ich bin nicht überzeugt, dass der gemeinsame Wortstamm *Zug* hier tatsächlich eine Rolle spielt und nicht vielmehr eine zufällige Übereinstimmung ist. Andere Dinge, die nicht einmal vom Wortstamm her mit der Eisenbahn zu tun haben, können schließlich auch entgleisen, beispielsweise "Projekte".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Aber Projekte haben einen Plan/roten Faden/Weg o. Ä., von dem sie abkommen können; Gesichtszüge nicht.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Gesichtszüge haben einen typischen Verlauf, dem sie im entspannten Zustand entsprechen (man könnte auch "folgen" sagen). Von diesem Verlauf weichen sie ab, wenn sie entgleisen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Man könnte "entgleisen" hier eine Metapher nennen. "Entgleisen" wird von seinem eigentlichen Bereich (Zug, der von den Schienen abkommt) auf Gesichtszüge hinübergetragen, die vor Angst/Schmerz/Freude/Kummer aus der Fassung geraten. Metaphorische Verwendungen im Wortschatz sind so häufig, dass sie uns oft gar nicht mehr auffallen.

Comment: Hier fehlt aber doch der entscheidende Zusammenhang von "Zug" nach dem ausdrücklich gefragt war.

Comment: @userunknown  Du kannst den Zusammenhang von Zug und Gesichtszügen ja noch im Detaill ausführen. Glaube aber, der Hinweis auf Zug, der entgleist, reicht vollauf.

Comment: Hm, "Gesichtszug" wird aber bereits bei Goethe und Schiller verwendet - da gab es noch keine Eisenbahn. Ebenso wie "entgleisen" im Sinne von "entgleiten". Ich spreche also dem Ausdruck des "Entgleisens von Gesichtszügen" jeglichen Zusammenhang mit Eisenbahnen ab.

Comment: Kannst du, aber unabhängig davon, wann Eisenbahnen  aufkamen , stellt sich bei entgleisen das Bild des Zuges ein und "entgleisen" ist für Metapher ein geeignetes Bild, wie oben bereits gesagt.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Züge sind aber älter als Eisenbahnen, etwa Ochsenzüge. Zus.. mit Takkats Gleisen mögen also bereits früher Wagen u. dgl. entgleist sein, die man Züge nannte. So oder so kann aber die Kombination "Gesichtszüge entgleisen" jüngeren Datums sein.

Comment: Also ich habe bei "entgleisen" zuerst einmal das Bild von einem Zug, der aus den Gleisen springt, im Kopf und habe noch nie an Ochsenkarren gedacht.

Comment: @rogermue: (oben) Das entscheidende ist hier, dass das Entgleisen keine gute, direkte Metapher für das ist, was mit dem Gesicht passiert. Erst über den Umweg 'Züge entgleisen' = Kontrollverlust = aufgesetzte Mimik fällt zusammen - Mimik=Gesichtszüge wird das Wortspiel verständlich. Das, was im Gesicht "Zug" genannt wird fällt aber nicht aus einem Gleis.

Comment: @rogermue (unten): Die Idee ist auch nicht, dass Gesichtszug nicht von dem Zug wie Eisenbahn oder Ochsenkarren abgeleitet ist. Vielleicht über das Zeichnen, das Ziehen der charakteristischen Linien mit der Feder. Aber Züge die entgleisen können sind nicht Luftzüge, Bowdenzüge, der Trinkzug aus einer Flasche, der Gebirgszug oder Mannnschaftszug beim Militär und eigentlich auch kein Gesichtszug - wohl aber Ochsenkarren oder Eisenbahnzüge.

Comment: Glaube nicht, das ein Leser allzu lange über die metaphorische Verwendung nachdenkt. Dazu ist der übertragene Gebrauch von entgleisen viel zu häufig. Der übertragene Gebrauch ist ja schon im Lexikon erfaßt.

Answer (score 11):

Vielleicht sollte man hier noch erwähnen, dass sowohl die "[Züge](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GZ09449#XGZ09449)" eines Gesichts als auch "[Gleis](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GG18885#XGG18885)" und "aus dem Gleis geraten" schon lange vor Erfindung der Eisenbahn ihren Einzug in die deutsche Sprache gefunden haben. Lediglich das Wort "entgleisen" kam erst mit den ersten Eisenbahnunfällen.

- Unter einem Gesichts**zug** verstand und versteht man auch heute noch die Zeichnung eines Gesichts, ursprünglich in Anlehnung an eine Verzierung eines Kunstwerks.
- Ein Gleis war schon im Althochdeutschen (*wagen-leis*) und seit Mittelhochdeutsch (*Geleis*) die Fahrspur eines Wagens. Im 18. Jahrhundert trat dann auch die Verwendung im übertragenen Sinn auf ("Gleis" als ein hergebrachter Zustand, die Bahn des Lebens oder die des Denkens).

  > Ich bin [...] schier [...] aus dem Glaisz meiner Erzehlung kommen. <sup>Grimmelshausen Simplicissimus 3 (1713)</sup>

Somit lag es auf der Hand, auch Gesichts**züge** aus dem **Gleis** (ihrer gewohnten Form) zu bringen, sie also **entgleisen** zu lassen. Eine schöne Analogie, die dadurch auch das Wortspiel mit den "Zügen" einer Eisenbahn schafft.

Auch nicht unerwähnt soll die mitunter falsch verwendete Flexion bleiben. Wenn es geschah, dass Gesichtszüge entgleisen, dann **entgleisten** sie oder sind **entgleist** (aber eben nicht "entglitten", wie man manchmal liest).

Comment: Gefragt war nach einem Fachwort für solche Konstrukte.

Comment: @userunknown: dann nenne es doch bitte (auch deshalb CW!), ich habe dafür kein Wort gefunden, meine aber dass es wegen der Etymologie keine Metapher sein kann... evtl. ein **Wortspiel (s.o)**.

Comment: Wortspiel ist zu unspezifisch, auch wenn es eines ist. Der Fakt, dass ich kein Wort dafür kenne, mutmaßlich weil es keins gibt, macht eine Antwort, die das Thema verfehlt in meinen Augen nicht besser. CW ist auch nur eine schlechte Ausrede. Wenn man keine Antwort hat, hat man keine - so einfach kann die Realität manchmal sein.

Comment: @Takkat: Wieso kann es denn keine Metapher sein, nur, weil die zusätzliche Übereinstimmung mit einem (Eisenbahn-)Zug nicht gegeben ist? Die Gesichtszüge liegen ja dennoch wörtlich betrachtet nicht in einem Gleis (auch wenn es sich dabei um die Fahrspur eines Wagens handelt) beziehungsweise bewegen sich nicht darauf; nur sinnbildlich gesprochen geraten sie aus dem "Gleis", dem sie normalerweise (bei entspanntem Gesichtsausdruck) folgen.

Comment: Das ist nun wirklich aber nicht die richtige Verwendung von Community Wiki. Diese Antwort braucht nun wirklich nicht von der Gemeinschaft gewartet werden. Es handelt sich ausschließlich um historische Bezüge, die sich ja nun kaum mehr ändern werden.

Answer (score 8):

*Entgleisen* bezieht sich nicht ausdrücklich auf Gleise im Zusammenhang mit Eisenbahnen. Man sagt beispielsweise auch "Diese Entgleisung ist nicht zu entschuldigen", wenn sich jemand unentschuldbar benommen hat.

Siehe DWDS:

> Gleis Geleise Geleis n. ‘aus zwei parallellaufenden Schienen bestehende Fahrspur’, spätmhd. geleise ‘Radspur, getretener Weg’ (14. Jh.) ist eine Kollektivbildung zu dem im Nhd. untergegangenen Substantiv mhd. leis(e) f. ‘Spur’, ahd. in waganleisa ‘Wagenspur’ (9. Jh.), das mit lat. līra (aus *leisā) ‘Ackerfurche’, dēlīrus ‘geistig aus dem Gleis gekommen, verrückt’ (s. ↗Delirium), aslaw. lě cha, russ. (landschaftlich) lechá (леха) ‘Beet, Ackerfurche’, lit. lýsė ‘Gartenbeet’ verwandt ist und zu der unter ↗leisten (s. d.) angeführten Wurzel ie. *leis- ‘am Boden gezogene Spur, Furche’ gehört. entgleisen Vb. ‘aus den Gleisen springen’, übertragen ‘vom rechten Weg abkommen, sich taktlos, ungeschickt benehmen’ (Mitte 19. Jh.).

Entgegen meiner ursprünglichen Meinung kommt dies bereits vor der Erfindung der Eisenbahn vor und steht somit nicht im Zusammenhang mit Eisenbahngleisen.

Auch die Gesichtszüge kommen wohl eher nicht vom Zug im Sinne von "Eisenbahn", sondern eher von "ziehen/zeichnen".

Von daher sehe ich in "Die Gesichtszüge entgleisen" auch keine Metapher in Bezug auf Eisenbahn. Es sind zwei Begriffe, die zufällig auch im Kontext von Eisenbahnen vorkommen, jedoch in diesem Zusammenhang hier nicht stehen.

Comment: Ach was wäre es schön, wenn Downvoter mal einen Kommentar hinterlassen würden...

Comment: Die Frage ist ja nicht einfach, wo "Gleise" herkommt, sondern speziell seit wann man von "entgleisen" spricht. Das Entgleisen der Gesichtszüge kann m.E. nicht als Metapher für das, was mit Mimik, Falten und Gesichtsfurchen, auf denen ja kein Fahrzeug fährt, gelten, sondern nur über den Umweg Gleise->Zug entgleist (Kontrollverlust) => Kontrollverlust über die Mimik => Gesichtszüge entgleisen hergestellt werden. Ein Kontrollverlust bei einem Flugzeug o. Ballon wäre etwa ein Absturz - "die Gesichtszüge stürzen ab" verwendet man aber nicht. Der Zshg. zum Zug kann m.E. kein Zufall sein.

Answer (score 4):

> Wie nennt man nun aber so ein Konstrukt, welches, die Wortähnlichkeit ausnutzend, so eine belustigende Parallele zieht?

Es wurde zwar schon in mehreren Kommentaren erwähnt, aber ich stelle es hier mal als eigene Antwort in den Raum: Man nennt so etwas ***[Wortspiel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortspiel)***, genauergesagt ein auf [Polysemie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemie) oder [Homonymie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonymie) beruhendes.

Ich zitiere [den Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wortspiel):

> Spiel mit Worten, dessen witziger Effekt besonders auf der Doppeldeutigkeit des gebrauchten Wortes […] beruht

Das einzige, was die *entgleisten Gesichtszüge* von anderen derartigen Wortspielen unterscheidet (vorausgesetzt, Deine Annahme über die Entstehung dieses Ausdruckes stimmt), ist, dass sie sich als feste Wendung verselbständigt haben.

Ich würde es nicht als Metapher einstufen, da sich der Ausdruck nicht in andere Sprachen übersetzen lässt, ohne die gefragte Eigenschaft verlieren. Dies hingegen ist eine charakteristische Eigenschaft des Wortspiels.

Comment: Mit anderen Worten: Du kennst kein ähnliches Wortspiel, welches sich als feste Redewendung etabliert hat? Mir scheint, es gäbe einen Ausdruck, mutmaßlich in Berliner Schnauze, bei dem mir so was schon mal begegnet ist, wo der Ausdruck auch so fest eingefahren ist, dass mir das zu Grunde liegende Wortspiel gar nicht aufgefallen ist. "Wortspiel" finde ich zu allgemein für die Frage. Wenn derartige Wortspiele aber so selten sind, dann ist verständlich, dass es dafür keinen eigenen Begriff gibt, bzw. dass man diesen nicht kennt.

Comment: *“Wortspiel” finde ich zu allgemein für die Frage* – Das hängt ein wenig davon ab, wie man die Frage interpretiert. Ich habe es so interpretiert, dass nicht nach einem Begriff gefragt wird, der die Verselbständigung beinhaltet, da dies nirgendwo erwähnt wird. Ich gestehe aber durchaus ein, dass man dies auch anders interpretieren kann und finde die entsprechende Frage auch durchaus interessant – kann sie aber leider nicht beantworten.

Comment: Verstehst Du das Beispiel des Dudens? M.E. ist das kein Beispiel, sondern eine Zusammenfassung in Telegrammstil.

Comment: @userunknown: Es ist ein Beispiel für die Verwendung des Wortes *Wortspiel,* zugegebenermaßen kein sonderlich tolles.

Comment: Wie heißt das Wortspiel? Wortspiel. Ich würde mich ja für so eine Bounty-Abgreifantwort schämen.

Comment: @userunknown: *Wortspiel* wurde in der Frage kein einziges Mal erwähnt und ich denke ehrlich, dass dies hier ein Fall ist, in dem man die Antwort nicht sieht, da sie zu naheliegend ist.

Comment: Es wurde nicht erwähnt weil es zu trivial ist. Dass es ein Wortspiel ist hat ja nun jeder sofort gesehen. Deswegen tauchte es auch nur beiläufig in anderen Antworten und Kommentaren auf. Es geht ganz offensichtlich um diese besondere Spielart eines Wortspiels.